# How to improve MongoDB performance with mongoose driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have 2 collections in MongoDB.

1. Document
2. Data

`Document` has around 5K documents and getting the total count was pretty fast.

But later I added one more collection `Data` which has 1M records. Now if I tried to get the Total count of records in `Document`, its taking 20s in Mongoose. But in the Mongo Console its faster.

//Document Schema

```
var docSchema = mongoose.Schema({
            docId: String,
            articleid: String,
            title:String,
            lastModified: String,
});
docSchema.index({ docId: 1, articleid: 1 ,lastModified:1});
var Doc = mongoose.model('document', docSchema);

module.exports = Doc;
```

//Data Schema

```
var allData = mongoose.Schema({
    _id:String,
    id: Number,
    author:String,    
});
allData.index({ id: 1});
var data = mongoose.model('Data', allMetricsData);

module.exports = data;
```

And the aggregate function in Node.JS is like:

```
 Document.count(function(errs, count) {
   console.log("Count is:",count);
 });
```

So how to improve the performance with Mongoose?

When I execute, `db.documents.count()` I'm getting the response instantly.

Comment: can you paste your mongoose query here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, don't forget to put index on all main fields use in your queries.

For example if all your query use the 'name' :

```
Collection.find({name: "aaa"})
```

or 'name' and 'age' :

```
Collection.find({name:"aaa", "age": 4})
```

Put index in your model as the following :

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose")

ActionCode = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:                   {type: String, default: ""},
    age:                    {type:Number, default: 0},
    otherfield:             {type:Number, default: 0},
});

ActionCode.index({name:1});
ActionCode.index({name:1, age: 1});

module.exports = mongoose.model('ActionCode', ActionCode);
```

Your index will be push into the ram, according to this the resolution of the document will be made faster.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/

Then, it can take times due to the amount of returned document, only select needed fields, like this mongo will return to your server only needed field instead of whole documents :

Example, if you need only name, age and type field:

```
 Collection.find({name: "aaa"},{name:1, age:1, field:1}, function(err, response){

        // returned documents here contains only following fields: _id, name, age, field
```

=======

Try

```
 Collection.find({}).select({_id: 1}).count(function(err, result)
```

Or try an aggregate :

```
Collection.aggregate([{$group:{_id: null, count:{$sum :1}}])
```

Comment: What might be the reason for the slowness of aggregate function?
Can Mongo not handle a million records?

Comment: 1/ miss of index, 2/ amount of data returned, 3/ inner optimisation of the aggregate

Comment: Added the index and still no change.
I'm doing aggregate on the collection which has 5K records how that will be affected?

Comment: So you have to improve the code of your aggregate, select only needed field, optimise your match.... Show your aggregate and your datas structures if you want more help

Comment: Updated the question with code.

When I execute `db.documents.count()` in mongo shell, I'm getting the result immediately.

Comment: see edits, try find().select().count(), and try the aggregate